# Show if $f$ : differentiable at $c$, then $\exists \epsilon >0 $ s.t. $f$ is continuous on $N(c, \epsilon)$

Tags: real-analysis

> Show if $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ : differentiable at $c$, then $\exists \epsilon >0 $ s.t. $f$ is continuous on $N(c, \epsilon)$.

---

**My try**

Since $f'(c) = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(c + h) - f(c)}{h}$, this means $\lim_{h \to 0} f(c + h) = f(c)$ (otherwise $f'(c)$ does not exists), which means $f$ is continuous on some neighbourhood of $c$.

But I'm stuck at showing this using $\epsilon$-$\delta$ method.

Comment: Observe $f(c+h)-f(c)<h\cdot f'(c)=\epsilon$.

Comment: Well your statement is false. A typical counter-example is $f(x) =x^2,x\in\mathbb{Q},f(x)=-x^2,x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb {Q} $. $f$ is continuous and differentiable at $0$ and at other points it is neither continuous nor differentiable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, defined as
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}&\text{for $x=\frac{1}{2n+1}$ and $n\in \mathbb{Z}$,}\\
0 &\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$
Is $f$ differentiable at $0$? Is $f$ continuous in $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon>0$?